# Change Yii2 assets directory to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, yii2, assets

This is my current assets setting.

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{

    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
    //...
```

I also have an account on AWS S3. I could upload/download files to S3 successful. 
Because I'm using heroku.com to run my website, all assets files will be removed when heroku's dynno is stopped restart. So I want to change assets directory to other server like S3.

How to change yii2 assets directory to AWS S3 ?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue ?

Comment: any update on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy.  Just change your sourcePath to the alias that you need. Here is example.

First create alias in you config/web.php

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'aliases'=>[
        '@test'=> 'https://s3.amazonaws.com'//change it to your amazon s3 path
    ],
    //other config
```

Then just add it to you AppAssets class or create another Asset.

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{

    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $sourcePath = '@test';
    public $css = [
    //...
```

Thats all.

Comment: will this write to s3 too? like the assets in `web\assets` folder to s3?